# How to freeze individual field of non-frozen dataclass?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

Is it possible to specify that a single field is frozen in a non-frozen dataclass? Something like this:

```py
@dataclass
class Data:
    fixed: int = field(frozen=True)
    mutable: int = field(frozen=False)

d = Data(2, 3)
d.mutable = 5   # fine
d.fixed = 7     # raises exception
```

I realize this can be done manually with properties and setters accessing a private data field, but then we lose some of the advantages of dataclasses: for one, the private data field needs a different name, which means the auto-generated constructor annoyingly has different parameter names than the fields.

Comment: `dataclasses` does not support this, but `attrs` (the project from which dataclasses was lifted) does: see https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/api.html#attr.setters.NO_OP

Answer (score 8):

I came here looking for the same but, like @wim said in comments, `dataclass` does not support this, but using `attrs` it is possible:

```py
from attrs import define, field
from attrs.setters import frozen

@define
class Data:
    fixed: int = field(on_setattr=frozen)
    mutable: int

d = Data(2, 3)
d.mutable = 5   # fine
d.fixed = 7     # raises exception
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import inspect
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields, field

@dataclass
class NamedDataclass:
    name: str = field(init=True)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        stack = inspect.stack()
        if len(stack) < 2 or stack[1].function != '__init__':
            assert key != 'name'
        super().__setattr__(key, value)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).